# count the number of terminal output lines

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am getting data by connecting to a Raspberry Pi 4 using a distance sensor.

In the code below, the sensor value is output directly to the terminal.

I want to write code in my python script that counts the number of sensor values ​​output to the terminal.

I am curious about the code to accurately count the number of terminal output lines.

Is there any way to store the number of terminal outputs as a variable?

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200)

def getTFminiData():
    while True:
        count = ser.in_waiting
        if count > 8:
            recv = ser.read(9)
            ser.reset_input_buffer()
            if recv[0] == 'Y' and recv[1] == 'Y': # 0x59 is 'Y'
                low = int(recv[2].encode('hex'), 16)
                high = int(recv[3].encode('hex'), 16)
                distance = low + high * 256
                print(distance)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if ser.is_open == False:
            ser.open()
        getTFminiData()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:   # Ctrl+C
        if ser != None:
            ser.close()
```

Comment: Does this code work?  Are you printing one `distance` value for each sensor value output?  If so, then just create a variable above your loop initially set to 0, and increment it by 1 whenever you print a sensor value.

Comment: Your reading logic seems suspect.  Why do you read 9 characters from the serial connection, but then only use 4 of them?  It doesn't seem to me that you should ever call `reset_input_buffer`.  What would that do except throw away valid input you haven't processed yet.

Comment: You are right. I have modified the code and verified that it works. Thanks for your advice.